# Polygons with coincident area and perimeter centroids

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polygons

Let $P$ be a simple, planar polygon.
Define $c_a$ as the *area centroid* of $P$, i.e., the center of gravity of the
closed shape $P$.
Define $c_p$ as the *perimeter centroid* of $P$,
the center of gravity of just the boundary edges of $P$.
One can compute $c_p$ as the weighted sum of the edge midpoints, weighted by
their length, and normalized by the total perimeter of $P$.

My question is:

> **Q**. Is there a clean characterization of those $P$ for which $c_a = c_p$?

Of course there are obvious examples (e.g., the regular polygons),
but there are also non-obvious examples.
Here is one I constructed:

---

[image: AreaPerimCG]

---

$$P=
((-1, 3), (-0.0426,
  0), (-1, -0.0213), (0, -0.0426), (1, -0.0213), (0.0426, 
  0), (1, 3), (0, 1)) \;,\; \implies c_a =c_p = (0,1.247)
$$

---

It seems these polygons are rare but not as uncommon as one might at first think.
It would be interesting to quantify "rare" and "not as uncommon."

Comment: with triangles, the area centroid equals the vertex centroid, but usually not the edge centroid. That surprised me at some point.

Comment: You should be able to take any two polygons (rotated so their four centroid points are all collinear) and glue appropriately scaled versions together with a thin corridor so that the resulting polygon has centroids that are coincident.

Comment: Posted similar (but not the same) question [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173903/centroids-of-a-polygon]
There is another fundamental centroid: mass center of vertices.
Are there any polygons, except regular, with all three centers coincide?

Comment: @lesobrod: That should be easy by sprinkling extra vertices collinear with edges in my example. These extra vertices will not change area or perimeter centroids, but will change the vertex centroid.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Hello, any progress on your question? I would be interested in knowing an upper bound for the distance between $c_a$ and $c_p$.

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson: Nope!