# Centroids of a polygon

Tags: geometry, polygons, centroid

Obviously, for any polygon we can define at least $3$ different centroids:
$C1:\;$ mass center of the lamina;
$C2:\;$ mass center of vertices with equal masses;
$C3:\;$ mass center of the perimeter.

For the triangle $C1 = C2 \ne C3$; for common, even convex, polygon $C1\ne  C2\ne  C3$:

[image]

I'm interested: *are there any theorems, facts or conjectures about these points?*

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the related question, [Polygons with coincident area and perimeter centroids](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1085227/237).

Comment: Note that C1,C2,C3 are the centroids of the 2-skeleton, 0-skeleton, 1-skeleton respectively-- perhaps they would be better named C0,C1,C2.  The only interesting fact I can think of is that for a simplex, the centroids of the 0- and n-skeleton are equal... not sure why.   Also see somewhat related question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1780630/can-a-convex-polygon-have-only-one-boundary-point-at-locally-maximum-distance-fr